# Does a tracer influence the arrow in any way

Tags: gear, archery

I'm in doubt if I should attach tracers to my arrows. Of course, they make them better visible but I've heard rumors that they *do* influence the arrow (other than stated by the manufacturer).

Do they influence the arrow? And if yes, in which way?

Tracer:

[image: Tracers]

> Arrow tracers are meant to give you increased downrange visibility.
>   They also double as an effective wind check! (We include this added
>   benefit free of charge) With today's high speed bows and faster arrows
>   seeing where your arrows go is an advantage. These bright colors will
>   help you track your arrows in flight and if you ever miss your target
>   will aid you in finding your lost arrow.
>
> By [Merlin Archery](http://www.merlinarchery.co.uk/gateway-feather-tracer.html)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A tricky one this. Some people swear they do, others swear they don't. Personally I have never used them as I always feared they might throw off my shot. There is no definitive evidence that they will have an impact however.

I can tell you that, even with a tracer, it's damned hard to find an arrow in grass. We used to use a metal detector to find them. Even the wooden arrows have a metal head.

Edit: as for tracking in flight, even a spotter would have a hard task seeing an arrow mid flight before it hit the target.